# CLAHE implementation on Vivado HLS

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, code-generation, vivado

I want to execute CLAHE algorithm (as used in MATLAB function `adapthisteq` ) in C / C++ because the function `adapthisteq` is not supported by codegen at present.

What are the alternatives?

I want to implement this on Xilinx Vivado HLS. Though OpenCV supports this algorithm, HLS doesn't have a synthesizable counterpart yet. What other alternatives do I have to get the source code of CLAHE algorithm in C, to work on Vivado HLS?

I am using MATLAB R2014b and Vivado 2014.4. (Both on Windows 7)

Comment: opencv has a CLAHE implementation ready for use. (you don't have to reinvent the wheel here)

Comment: @berak I know OpenCV has a CLAHE implementation. But VivadoHLS doesn't support this particular OpenCV function. (VivadoHLS does support many OpenCV functions, but not all).

Answer (score 2):

Good news! You don't have to re-implement it. OpenCV has a CLAHE implementation and Vivado HLS has [OpenCV support](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/HLS+Video+Library).

```
Mat m= imread("lena.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); //input image
imshow("lena_GRAYSCALE",m);

Ptr<CLAHE> clahe = createCLAHE();
clahe->setClipLimit(4);

Mat dst;
clahe->apply(m,dst);
imshow("lena_CLAHE",dst);

waitKey();
```

** Code Shamelessly taken from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12024/use-of-clahe/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. But, unfortunately, _Though OpenCV supports this algorithm, HLS doesn't have a synthesizable counterpart yet._ Not all the OpenCV functions can be implemented in VivadoHLS. You can see the last couple of comments in [this link](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/Error-using-CLAHE-OpenCV-on-Vivado-HLS/m-p/560852#M2962).